# Why ServerSocket doesn't invoke NetworknOnMainThread while Socket does?

Tags: android, exception, network-programming

```
server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
```

does not invoke NetworkOnMainThreadException on my application which I think it should do and edit the code to run on another Thread while

```
socket= new Socket(ADDRESS,PORT);
```

does invoke NetworkOnMainThreadException properly. Did I miss something or is it an error that should be fixed?

Comment: Since ~99.44%, Android apps are creating regular `Sockets`, not `ServerSockets`, my guess is that they did not bother to put in the exception for the `ServerSocket`.

That being said, doing network I/O using *any* socket is a bad idea, and if you would like them to add the exception, file a feature request on http://b.android.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should it? `new ServerSocket(...)` is just a local operation. It doesn't involve any actual network activity, whereas `new Socket(...)` does, and it can block for up to a minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

When you call new Socket(ADDRESS,PORT);

```
private Socket(SocketAddress address, SocketAddress localAddr,
413                    boolean stream) throws IOException {
414         setImpl();
415 
416         // backward compatibility
417         if (address == null)
418             throw new NullPointerException();
419 
420         try {
421             createImpl(stream);
422             if (localAddr != null)
423                 bind(localAddr);
424             if (address != null)
425                 connect(address);
426         } catch (IOException e) {
427             close();
428             throw e;
429         }
430     }
```

It creates the stream. whereas `server = new ServerSocket(PORT);`

```
public ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr) throws IOException {
230        setImpl();
231        if (port < 0 || port > 0xFFFF)
232            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
233                       "Port value out of range: " + port);
234        if (backlog < 1)
235          backlog = 50;
236        try {
237            bind(new InetSocketAddress(bindAddr, port), backlog);
238        } catch(SecurityException e) {
239            close();
240            throw e;
241        } catch(IOException e) {
242            close();
243            throw e;
244        }
245    }
```

**NOTICE** there is no `connect();` which leaves to none of those methods involves network operations hence you will not get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: The fact that there is no `connect()` isn't a sufficient answer. The point is that there is no activity on the network at all, and no blocking.

Comment: connect() method does the acutal network. therefore there isn't network on the main thread?

Comment: There are many methods that do network operations and block. `connect()` is one of them. The fact that it isn't being called isn't a sufficient explanation. The explanation is that *none* of them is being called.

Comment: And instead of just saying none of them is being called, I showed the source code of what is being called. Answering a question can have different approaches. Not only the one you think is right.

Comment: Just quoting source code isn't an answer at all, and 'notice there is no `connect()`' remains insufficient.

Comment: Source code is where the answer can be found and proof. Saying 'It doesn't involve any network operations' is a statement without prove and/or evidence.

Comment: 1. Source code would have been an answer if you had also said that none of those methods involves network operations. You didn't say that, so you haven't said anything. 2. By itself the source code doesn't prove that either, but 3. The OP isn't asking for proof, he is just asking for an answer, and you haven't provided even that.

Comment: And would adding 'none of those methods involves network operations' end this conversation? If you feel its not a useful answer you can downvote it. I assume people can read code, after pointing them where to look at and the differences. I also answered after he marked yours as right answer because I just want to leave a reference or proof for others who view this. So if adding that ends this conversation Ill be happy to.